# When is a NSURLResponse not a NSHTTPURLResponse?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I've seen a lot of code, including Apple's SimpleURLConnections sample, that simply cast any NSURLResponse to a NSHTTPURLResponse. If it is always a NSHTTPURLResponse why do the NSURLConnections not return NSHTTPURLResponse?

I'm worried that if I simply downcast the response, I'm introducing buggy code.

For instance, is it OK to do this without checking isKindOfClass?

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
 NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)redirectResponse;
 // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is ok if you are sure that your connection runs via HTTP protocol:

> An NSHTTPURLResponse object represents a response to an HTTP URL load request. It’s a subclass of NSURLResponse that provides methods for accessing information specific to HTTP protocol responses.

If you are connecting via FTP, for example, then casting `NSURLResponse` to `NSHTTPURLResponse` will be incorrect.

Comment: HTTP response codes must be 3 digits long, if you are getting more than that length, is not a valid HTTP response code.

Comment: I suggest to do a better type-checking than just a cast, I have many cases of crashes related to NSURLResponse NOT being an NSHTTPURLResponse even though I'm only dealing with HTTP connections.

Answer (score 21):

The safer way to do it is with introspection.

```
if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
   NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)redirectResponse;
   // do stuff
}
```