# NSHTTPURLResponse becomes NSURLResponse

Tags: ios, http, nsurlconnection

I am using if-modified-since in the HTTP header to decide if I should download file.
App was tested and everything was OK, but now I am getting errors when I ask my NSHTTPURLResponse instance `response.statusCode` or `[[response allHeaderFields] objectForKey:@"Last-Modified"]`.

It seems to be just NSURLResponse. What are the possible reasons?

I've read[this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396966/when-is-a-nsurlresponse-not-a-nshttpurlresponse) but the problem still is not clear for me.
Thanks in advance!
UPD:
some code:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];  
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  

        NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  
        [myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];  
        df.dateFormat = @"EEE',' dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'";  
        df.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];  
        df.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];  

        [myRequest addValue:[df stringFromDate:lastModifiedLocal]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-Modified-Since"];

        myRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;

        NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;  
        NSError* error = nil;

        NSData* data =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request              returningResponse:&response error:&error];  

        if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending request: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
//As was advised
        NSHTTPURLResponse* newResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
//crash here        
NSLog(@"%d", newResp.statusCode);
```

**UPD:**
Error in code - myRequest and request are different variables. Problem solved.

Comment: What is the result for `data` after the `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`? Also, Why not try passing in an actual `NSError` pointer so if something goes wrong you might possibly know what it is, by logging `error.localizedDescription`?

Comment: Data is normal, just as I expect.

Comment: There was a mistake because of my stupid unconcentration - 
`[myRequest addValue:[df stringFromDate:lastModifiedLocal]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-Modified-Since"];

        myRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData;` and
 `NSData* data =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request              returningResponse:&response error:&error];` after it, another variable with local URL, so no HTTP there. Sorry. Will approve most complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very likely that the request is failing and no response object is being generated. You can check this as follows:

```
if (response) {
    NSHTTPURLResponse* newResp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    NSLog(@"%d", newResp.statusCode);
}
else {
    NSLog(@"No response received");
}
```

As was suggested by another commenter, you should probably include an NSError object so you can check errors more effectively:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
NSError *error = nil;  
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: &error];
```

Then, you can check the error before checking the response:

```
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error sending request: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: I've done error logging and error is 0x0, so there is no info. Code updated, thanks.

Comment: Also return data is OK, just HTTP-header in broken, I guess. Tests on servers side tell that everything is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast it:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse 
{
    self.response = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)aResponse;
}
```

**Edit**

Your response is NULL. Try this:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: How and when are you setting response? And what type of class is response?

Comment: Updated again, still no. +1 for your help.

Comment: Can you try passing in an error pointer and see if there are any errors?